# Using a Rapier in your Off Hand?

Tags: savage-worlds

You get a +1 to Parry using a Rapier. If you hold a Rapier in your *Off Hand* do you still get the +1 to Parry?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Yes, it does**

The only penalty from using a rapier in your off hand is that you can't use that hand for something else. The +1 parry still applies. Source: [Official Rules Forum](http://www.peginc.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=24498)

Also, I second @aramis as another former SCA fencer. Makes total sense.

Answer (score 7):

You probably should. It's not significantly harder in Real Life to parry with the off hand rapier than it is with the good hand.

(I was for 10 years a SCA Rapier fencer. 
Hope to be again.)

Comment: But there are so many more interesting things you can use in your off hand in SCA fencing ...

Comment: But they still don't allow Off-hand opponent...